# Draggable group, doesn't change nodes positions which are in group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var selectedGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable: true,
});

var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    fill: 'red',
    radius: 10,
});

circle.on('dblclick', function () {
    console.log('x: ' + circle.getX() + ' y: ' + circle.getY());
});

selectedGroup.add(circle);
layer.add(selectedGroup);
stage.add(layer);
layer.draw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cekB3/3/

- When I double click on the circle, its position is [10,10]
- When I move that circle and I double click on it, its position is [10,10]

Why isn't the position changing? Am i doing something wrong? or is it a bug?

I've noticed that when I change circle to draggable, then its coordinates change, but then I have an issue with 2 circles in one group and I want to be able to move them all at the same time and have their x and y changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To add to @thescottknight's good answer:**

You can move an object between containers using `myObject.moveTo(newContainer)`

So you can move circle2 from `selectedGroup` to the same coordinate position on `layer` like this:

```
circle2.on('dblclick', function () {
    circle2.setX(selectedGroup.getX()+circle2.getX());    
    circle2.setY(selectedGroup.getY()+circle2.getY());
    circle2.moveTo(layer);
    layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the circle's position isn't changing is that `getX` and `getY` are relative to the parent element. The parent element is the `selectedGroup` draggable. There are 2 ways to get the changing position of the circle.

1. Use the `getAbsolutePosition` function on the circle to get its position:

   ```
   pos = circle.getAbsolutePosition();
   console.log('position=(' + pos.x + ', ' + pos.y + ')');
   ```
2. Use the position of the draggable and the offset of the circle:

   ```
   console.log('x: ' + (selectedGroup.getX() + circle.getX()) + ' y: ' + (selectedGroup.getY() + circle.getY()));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but then i come across to other problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/cekB3/9/ I want to be able to remove those 2 circles from group, and let them be in same place.